# Calculate volume and surface area of sphere in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program which asks for the radius of a sphere, and depending on if the user inputs if they want the volume or the surface area, then that's what the program will return.
(Before anyone says anything about the program not being done, I know, I'm just trying to get the foundation to work before I add the formula for the volume etc.)

Unfortunately, I can't even get this much to compile because it doesn't seem to acknowledge that I declared the radius.

Chances are, I made some careless mistakes, but after all, we learn and grow from my mistakes.

I don't want this completed for me, I just want guidance for where I went wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void sphereArea();
void sphereVolume();

double pi = 3.141596,
double radius = 0.0;

int main()
{

cout << "Please enter the radius of your sphere" << endl;
cin >> radius;
sphereArea();
system ("pause");
}

void sphereVolume(){

}

void sphereArea(){
double Vol;
Vol = ((4.0 / 3.0) * pi * (radius ^ 3));
cout << "The volume of your sphere is " << Vol << endl;
}
```

Edit: Currently I am getting these errors:
1. On line 27 -> error C2296: '^': illegal, left operand has type 'double' 
2. Also on line 27 (with regards to radius) -> IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Comment: Perhaps you can adapt [this program](http://www0.us.ioccc.org/1988/westley.c)? :)

Comment: what error are you getting? at what line?

Comment: `double pi = 3.141596,` That shouldn't be a comma at the end.

Comment: Read the *first* error message. The that tells you what is wrong where you declare radius.

Comment: "*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include** the desired behavior, a specific problem or **error** [...]*"

Comment: We dont learn and grow from your mistakes. You do.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi I meant that people in general learn from their mistakes.

Comment: Stackoverflow is now à compiler.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for that.

Comment: These issues are pretty trivial, so it is worth examining your code more before posting here.

Comment: Watch out, the formula you are using is for the volume, but you have put it in the `sphereArea` function. It should be in `sphereVolume` instead.

Comment: @badfilms like I said, I had a feeling I made some careless mistakes. The problem is, I tend to overlook the smallest mistakes.

Comment: Debugging is a very important part of writing code. Issues such as putting a comma as an end line are the types of issues that you need to teach yourself to catch. Not understanding how to use cmath requires a little bit of digging up the STL to learn everything you need to know about it. Asking questions is good, but you should try to solve the problem first, especially in these early stages.

Comment: @badfilms would it be sad if I said that I looked over my code numerous times and didn't catch it? :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Vol = ((4.0 / 3.0) * pi * (radius ^ 3));
```

`^` is not a power. It's a bit-xor operator.
The reason why you're getting an error is that you can't do a bitwise operation on floats.
Change this line to this:

```
Vol = ((4.0 / 3.0) * pi * (radius * radius * radius));
```

or you can use the `pow()` function. Like this:

```
Vol = ((4.0 / 3.0) * pi * (std::pow(radius, 3)));
```